# How do i debug when i can't even console.log the variable?

Tags: javascript, debugging, bcrypt

my question here is how do i debug the code below. My problem was that i forgot to pass the bcrypt paramater into the function. That means that `const isValid = bcrypt.compareSync(password, data[0].hash)`  doesnt execute. But i dont get an error and i can't console.log the variable `isValid` either. The only error i get from the `else` statement is `res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials !")`. That must be the case because `isValid` evaluates to `false` and jumps to the `else` statement. But why does it evaluate to `false` when i can't even print out the variable ?

Just to recap, i know how to make the code work but i just want to know how i would debug this.

```
  const { email, hash, password } = req.body;
  db.select("email","hash")
  .from("login").where("email", "=", email )
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
    const isValid = bcrypt.compareSync(password, data[0].hash);
    
    if(isValid) {
      db.select("*")
        .from("users")
        .where("email", "=", email)
        .then(user => {
          res.json(user[0])
      }).catch(err => res.status(400).json("Unable to get User"));
    } else {
      res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials !")
    }
  }).catch(err => res.status(400).json("Wrong Credentials"));
}
```

Comment: "*That must be the case because `isValid` evaluates to false and jumps to the else statement.*" - no. It might also be that `compareSync` throws an exception, the promise rejects, and control flow jumps to the `.catch()` callback. Do not ignore the `err` parameter in there, at least `console.error(err);` it!

Comment: Don't do debugging with `console.log` statements. Do debugging with a debugger and breakpoints, stepping through the code line by line. You can also make it break on exceptions.